# I haven't a clue

Tags: riddle, cryptic-clues

A shot and two dances,
really don't know.

Seeing you double,
really in two.

That time already,
five o'clock, phew.

It's all a failure,
graded so low.

Number of letters:

> 3

Hint 1:

> NATO involvement?  You can't be serious.  You must be joking.

Hint 2:

> If you're not getting it you're probably thinking it.

Comment: number of letters are usually given in cryptic clues.

Comment: @manshu thanks, didn't realize that. Done :) )

Comment: NATO involvement and two dances reminds me of the NATO phonetic alphabet, where F=Foxtrott and T=Tango.

Comment: @Gamow I was thinking exactly the same thing, where the shot is W = Whiskey

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is:

> WTF

The first pair of lines describes the full three-letter word:

A shot and two dances:

> Whiskey, Tango and Foxtrot from the NATO Alphabet (Hint 1)

The following three line pairs describe the three letters.

Seeing you double:

> Reference to W (double-u)

5 o'clock

> T-time = Tea time  (credit to Gamow)

It's all a failure, graded so low:

> The F is the lowest grade you can get, and will make you fail a class